# Can you get Tableau to work with sparse columns?

Tags: database, reporting, sparse-matrix, tableau-api

We are evaluating Tableau and noticed that it doesn't appear to recognize sparse columns in our SQL Server 2008 tables. Is this possible or are there any common workarounds?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use it like that, the visualization will cut off the parts that are empty, that's all.

Answer (score 0):

Tableau displays the columns it finds from a SELECT * query.
In reviewing this blog we see that SELECT * omits SPARSE columns.  https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sreekarm/2009/01/08/sparse-columns-in-sql-server-2008/

You would have to explicitly name the columns you want to see using a CUSTOM SQL connection in Tableau.